# Not mutate module state in the Vuex store. Vuex | Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm exploring vuex modules feature and I can't figure out what I do wrong.

I have a simple vuex store with one module.

The module contains a state and mutation option, where just adding a new item in the module state.

When I trying to call the mutation function, it doesn't work.

**Codesandbox** => https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-fire-2p3eq?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Questions should contain all relevant code and not depend on external links to explain the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action has combined the context and payload arguments into one instead of keeping them separate:

```html
addItem({ commit }, payload) {  ✅  // Correct
```

```html
addItem({ commit, payload }) {  ❌  // Incorrect
```

Another problem is your module's `state` is an array instead of an object, and is being used directly, as if it was a state item.  Make `state` an object, and put the item data into an array property:

```js
state: {
  items: [
    { id: "1", name: "1" },
    { id: "2", name: "2" },
    { id: "3", name: "3" }
  ]
}
```

Change your computed to use this `items` property:

```js
const ItemsState = computed(() => store.state.a.items);
```

In the mutation, push the new value (what you had before would not change `state` at all because it just changes the function argument reference):

```js
SET_NEW_ITEM(state, payload) {
  state.items.push(payload);
}
```

You *don't* need an action to call this:

```js
function addItem() {
   let newItem = { id: "5", name: "5" };
   store.commit('a/SET_NEW_ITEM', newItem)
}
```

Here is your [updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-raman-rqosf)

Answer (score 2):

you have to call from the actions

```
const addTheme = ({ commit }, { description }) => {
 commit(SET_NEW_ITEM, {
    description
  });
...
}
```

and in mutation you have to create a function with the same name SET_NEW_ITEM:

```
const SET_NEW_ITEM = (state, description) => {

}
```

Comment: I know that I can use the actions.

Usually, the action function needs when you have some asynchronous operations or need to committing multiple mutations inside an action function.

In this example, I don't have any asynchronous operations, also I do not need to commit a few mutation functions by using an action function.

Thank you very much for your reply @x-rw but there possible without the action function.

Look at that - https://scrimba.com/scrim/cqKK4psq?pl=pnyzgAP